# iOS Swift: SearchController with a StoryBoard UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uisearchbar

Evening, I have built a **search controller**, and I have also the code to programmatically create his **search bar**. But I would like to replace this code with a search bar designed in the **story board**.

**So my question is, how can I connect the outlet to the search controller?**

this is my code:

```
public class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

    public var customSearchBar = UISearchBar()

    override public var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return self.customSearchBar
        }
    }
}

func configureSearchController() {

    searchController = CustomSearchController()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.customSearchBar = self.customSearchBar

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

}

extension EarthSearcherTableViewController : UISearchResultsUpdating {

    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //Code
        guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        self.getLocations(forSearchString: text)
    }

    fileprivate func getLocations(forSearchString searchString: String) {

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchString
        request.region = mapView.region

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in

            guard let response = response else { return }
            self.locations = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @objc func zoomToCurrentLocation() {


        //Clear existing pins
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        mapView.add(MKCircle(center: location.coordinate, radius: 50))


    }

}
```

I think I have a problem with the delegates, because when I type in the search bar, the results does not show off in the table

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subclass `UISearchController` and override `searchBar` getter to return the searchBar that you want.

```
public class mySearchController: UISearchController {

    public var customSearchBar = UISearchBar()
    override public var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return customSearchBar
        }
    }
}
```

In your method, set the `customSearchBar` to your `searchBar`.

```
func configureSearchController() {    
    searchController = mySearchController()
    searchController.customSearchBar = self.searchBar
    //Other stuff...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, can you give me some code please? I'm a newbie

Comment: @TheMiotz Check it out now.

Comment: Thank you! one thing is missing, I don't know how to integrate the delegates now

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, but you can use the `searchController` as you were using before. Just do `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`

Comment: ok but now when i type in the search bar, I can't see anymore the results in the table view. I update my code

Comment: What is the `searchController.customSearchBar = self.customSearchBar` line? make sure that you assign correct `searchBar` that you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139256/discussion-between-the-miotz-and-orkhan-alikhanov).